# How does Python treat multiple IF statements NOT nested?

Tags: python, if-statement

This question was already answered:

• How does Python treat multiple IF's that are NOT nested?

(The actual code does not help answer the above question.)

Comment: Please read my question.. I KNOW (& agree) I should not use this.. but HAVE TO FOR A TEST..  I am asking: "What does Python do in that situation?"

Comment: See the section The Elif Statement
in https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Python_Concepts/If_Statement

A block of if, elif, elif, else will only execute one of the cases, in the order they are written. The else will only be evaluated if all the other tests are false.

Comment: Thanks Curt!  That helps.. I think this test SUUUCKS and is purposely causing a deficiency in the code to cause me to compensate for it elsewhere.  (or to help further understand the behavior of python in this case)

Comment: If you simply show a representative part of the code it would be more clear what you mean.

Comment: I would have, but it's irrelevant the actual question.  The question was on the behavior of Python in that case, not a question on a solution to the code or get the code to do x.. question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python Interpreter will evaluate multiple non-nested `if` statements sequentially. That is if there are no `elif` or `else` clauses, The first `if` statement will be evaluated, then the second, third, and so on.